# Android runnable on thread called multiple times

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, asmack, android-handler

I am trying to implement MUC with aSmack, but seem to be unable to update the UI with the ArrayAdapter correctly.
I have set up my listener in my **ChatService.java** like this:

```
connection.addPacketListener(new MessageListener(), new PacketFilter() {
            public boolean accept(Packet packet) {
                Message msg = (Message) packet;
                return msg.getBody() != null;
            }});
```

And my listener class looks like this:

```
private class MessageListener implements PacketListener {
    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public MessageListener() {
    }

    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
        if(packet instanceof Message ) {
            Message message = (Message) packet;

            android.os.Message aosMessage = new android.os.Message();
            aosMessage.what = message.getType().ordinal();
            aosMessage.obj = message;
            messageHandler.handleMessage(aosMessage);

        }
    }

}
```

Now the problem is as follows;
First, I tried updating the UI via the handler (the handler is defined in my **ChatActivity.java**):

```
private final Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
private Message chatMessage;

@Override
public void handleMessage(final android.os.Message msg) {
    chatMessage = (Message) msg.obj; 

    if(Message.Type.values()[msg.what].equals(Message.Type.groupchat)) {
        conversationArrayAdapter.add("Received group message:  " + chatMessage.getBody());
    } else if (Message.Type.values()[msg.what].equals(Message.Type.chat)) { 
        conversationArrayAdapter.add("Received private message:  " + chatMessage.getBody());
    }
}
};
```

But this won't update the UI until an interaction is introduced from the user's end.
After a little web-digging, I realized I need to use the post (or runonUIthread) method to implement this, and so I tried:

```
private final Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
private Message chatMessage;

@Override
public void handleMessage(final android.os.Message msg) {
    chatMessage = (Message) msg.obj; 
    
    this.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(Message.Type.values()[msg.what].equals(Message.Type.groupchat)) {
                conversationArrayAdapter.add("Received group message:  " + chatMessage.getBody());
                conversationArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (Message.Type.values()[msg.what].equals(Message.Type.chat)) { 
                conversationArrayAdapter.add("Received private message:  " + chatMessage.getBody());
                conversationArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
}
};
```

But now the run() method is called **multiple** times (confirmed on debug), and the UI is updated with a seemingly-random-amount of the same messages (different amount of repetitions for every message, but all the messages are shown).

This is my first android app (but I am a java developer by trade), and I am quite sure I am doing something wrong in regards to the architecture here. Any assistance (preferably a detailed one - with code samples and / or references to the correct areas of the documentation) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

### Corrected working snippet after @Emil's answer

```
private class MessageListener implements PacketListener {
    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public MessageListener() {
    }

    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
        if(packet instanceof Message ) {
            Message message = (Message) packet;

            android.os.Message aosMessage = new android.os.Message();
            aosMessage.what = message.getType().ordinal();
            aosMessage.obj = message;
            aosMessage.setTarget(messageHandler);
            aosMessage.sendToTarget();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `handleMessage` directly :

```
messageHandler.handleMessage(aosMessage);
```

You should obtain a message from a given `Handler` or `setTarget(Handler handler)` on a message and then call `sendToTarget()` on the message to get it to be sent and processed by the `Handler`. If you implement the `Handler` correctly you don't need the `post` for this.

Comment: Thank you! This worked wonderfully! Will edit the question to share the corrected code.

Comment: It would be better if you posted the answer that worked for you *as a new answer and accept it*. You can still upvote Emils answer.